# Get branch points of equation

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

If I have a general function,`f(z,a)`, `z` and `a` are both real, and the function `f` takes on real values for all `z` except in some interval `(z1,z2)`, where it becomes complex. How do I determine `z1` and `z2` (which will be in terms of `a`) using Mathematica (or is this possible)? What are the limitations?

For a test example, consider the function `f[z_,a_]=Sqrt[(z-a)(z-2a)]`. For real `z` and `a`, this takes on real values except in the interval `(a,2a)`, where it becomes imaginary. How do I find this interval in Mathematica?

In general, I'd like to know how one would go about finding it mathematically for a general case. For a function with just two variables like this, it'd probably be straightforward to do a contour plot of the Riemann surface and observe the branch cuts. But what if it is a multivariate function? Is there a general approach that one can take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have appears to be a Riemann surface parametrized by 'a'. Consider the algebraic (or analytic) relation g(a,z)=0 that would be spawned from this branch of a parametrized Riemann surface. In this case it is simply g^2 - (z - a)*(z - 2*a) == 0. More generally it might be obtained using Groebnerbasis, as below (no guarantee this will always work without some amount of user intervention).

```
grelation = First[GroebnerBasis[g - Sqrt[(z - a)*(z - 2*a)], {x, a, g}]]
```

Out[472]= 2 a^2 - g^2 - 3 a z + z^2

A necessary condition for the branch points, as functions of the parameter 'a', is that the zero set for 'g' not give a (single valued) function in a neighborhood of such points. This in turn means that the partial derivative of this relation with respect to g vanishes (this is from the implicit function theorem of multivariable calculus). So we find where grelation and its derivative both vanish, and solve for 'z' as a function of 'a'.

```
Solve[Eliminate[{grelation == 0, D[grelation, g] == 0}, g], z]
```

Out[481]= {{z -> a}, {z -> 2 a}}

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: @d'o-o'b Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I had switched variables from earlier testing, but failed to do so uniformly. If you just give the variable of interest to GroebnerBasis, I think that will work. For your example: First[GroebnerBasis[..., x] should do what you have in mind. My example should have a similar change, so instead of specifying {x,a,g} we just specify z.

Comment: I will add that the confusion in my code reflects a bit of confusion on my part. I believe what will (often) work is to specify, in the variable list, all the variables that appear in denominators, radicals, etc. That is to say, those variables in which the input is not already a polynomial. In my first example that would be {z,a}. In yours it would be {b,x}.

Comment: @Daniel: The `Eliminate` step has been running for over a day on my laptop. Now I'm not that advanced at mma, so do you know of some way to supply conditions (for e.g., some of them are non-zero, real, etc. so mma doesn't have to worry about dividing by zero, etc.)... for now, I've resigned to just waiting for it to finish whenever it does (which looks like never).

Comment: @d'o-o'b My main recommendation is to replace Eliminate[eqns,elimvars] by GroebnerBasis[polys,keepvars,elimvars,MonomialOrder->EliminationOrder] where polys is obtained by subtracting rhs from lhs of eqns. There may be other tactics to employ but that's where I would start. If you post the actual input you have then I'll play around with them.

Comment: whooa!!! that was blazing fast. That solved in 10 seconds, what `Eliminate` couldn't do in 1.5 days!!! Thank you very much! As a side note, why this huge disparity in compute times? How can I know which method to choose?

Comment: @d'o-o'b Eliminate uses some fairly old code. Might get updated some day. Solve alone can do these things reasonably fast if you know how to tell it, nicely, to eliminate variables. Prior to version 8 that was done via an optional third argument. It still "works", though with a warning message. There is a proper way to do it but I never remember what it is, and did not manage to find it in documentation (probably there though, cowering in some corner).

Answer (score 2):

For polynomial systems (and some class of others), `Reduce` can do the job.

E.g.

```
In[1]:= Reduce[Element[{a, z}, Reals] 
           && !Element[Sqrt[(z - a) (z - 2 a)], Reals], z]
Out[1]= (a < 0 && 2a < z < a) || (a > 0 && a < z < 2a)
```

This type of approach also works (often giving very complicated solutions for functions with many branch cuts) for other combinations of elementary functions I checked.

To find the branch cuts (as opposed to the simple class of branch points you're interested in) in general, I don't know of a good approach.  The best place to find the detailed conventions that Mathematica uses is at the [functions.wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/) site.

I do remember reading a good paper on this a while back... I'll try to find it....

---

That's right! The easiest approach I've seen for branch cut analysis uses the [unwinding number](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/235699.235705). There's a paper "[Reasoning about the elementary functions of complex analysis](http://www.springerlink.com/content/uql8qdy6an2aqp4u/)" about this the the journal "Artificial Intelligence and Symbolic Computation". It and similar papers can be found at one of the authors homepage: http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/offprints.html.

Comment: Here's a post about this at [mapleprimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/36148-Unwinding-Number-Some-Rules-For-Working)

Comment: @d'o-o'b: Don't be too hasty in accepting this poor excuse for an answer. You might discourage someone who actually knows what they're talking about from posting...

Comment: Although I don't see anything wrong with your approach, you're right. I accepted because it returned what I expected, however I should wait to see if someone else has a better approach. Also, this is not a suitable approach for more complicated functions.. some that are seemingly simple, such as a general cubic. it didn't compute even after 15 hours of run time on an MBP.

Answer (score 2):

For general functions you cannot make Mathematica calculate it. 
Even for polynomials, finding an exact answer takes time. 
I believe Mathematica uses some sort of quantifier elimination when it uses Reduce, 
which takes time.

Without any restrictions on your functions (are they polynomials, continuous, smooth?)
one can easily construct functions which Mathematica cannot simplify further:
    f[x_,y_] := Abs[Zeta[y+0.5+x*I]]*I

If this function is real for arbitrary x and any -0.5 < y < 0 or 0<y<0.5,
then you will have found a counterexample to the Riemann zeta conjecture, 
and I'm sure Mathematica cannot give a correct answer.

Comment: thanks. I've pretty much come to that conclusion. My equation is an irreducible cubic and I haven't been able to get anything out of MMA.